# Keyboard and USB hub are only picking power from USB port, but they're not transferring data

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

I recently bought a USB hub — [Promate Masterhub](https://www.promate.net/products/masterhub?variant=13283138076737) (High Performance 10-port USB Hub with Four USB 3.0 and Six USB 2.0 Ports) — because I needed a larger amount of USB ports. All of a sudden I noticed that devices connected to it stopped working, I tried to plug it in another USB port on my laptop but still wasn't working.

I had a keyboard and mouse connected to it and tried to connect them directly to my laptop and the mouse was working but the keyboard was not. Seems like the keyboard is only picking power from the USB because some leds turn on(the RGB lighting is not working tho). Same with the USB hub, it can power a laptop cooler.

The keyboard is not working even if I plug it in another laptop. My idea is that the keyboard malfunctioned and it damaged the USB hub in the process. It's very weird because I had the devices for just a couple of days.

Do you think there is something to be done or should I send the devices to the warranty because the usb cables are damaged?

Comment: What is the make and model of the USB hub? It honestly sounds like it’s dead.

Comment: It's this one https://www.promate.net/products/masterhub?variant=13283138076737

Comment: Something is wrong with the hub. Contact the manufacturer.